# Discord.py cogs not loading on startup

Tags: python, discord.py

I have problems making the role commands. I'm pretty sure it should work just fine; there's no error and there aren't any warnings in the terminal. The bot doesn't execute the command for some reasons

```
# Code Structure
project/
├── skadi.py
└── misc/
    └── roles.py
```

## skadi.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

import os
import asyncio

from discord.interactions import Interaction

from discord.ui import Button, button, View
from tickets.ticket import CreateButton
from tickets.popup import CloseButton, TicketForm

from variables import *


discord.utils.setup_logging()




intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True


Skadi = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)



@Skadi.remove_command("help")

@Skadi.event 
async def on_ready():
    await Skadi.tree.sync()
    print("Da Skadi was awoken")
    SHMOL_GUILD = Skadi.get_guild(SHMOL_ID)
    
    if SHMOL_GUILD:
        SHMOL_MEMBERS = SHMOL_GUILD.member_count
        
        await Skadi.change_presence(
            status=discord.Status.idle,
            activity=discord.Activity(
                type=discord.ActivityType.watching,
                name=f"{SHMOL_MEMBERS} members. | {SHMOL_GUILD.name} "
            )
        )
    else:
        print("SHMOL guild not found.")

    Skadi.add_view(CreateButton())
    Skadi.add_view(CloseButton())

@Skadi.event
async def on_message(message):
    if Skadi.user.mention in message.content.split():
        await message.reply(f'Yes?!', mention_author=False)




async def load():

    for filename in os.listdir('./misc'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
         await Skadi.load_extension(f"misc.{filename[:-3]}")

    for filename in os.listdir('./tickets'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
         await Skadi.load_extension(f"tickets.{filename[:-3]}")

async def main(): 
    await load()
    await Skadi.start(SKADI_TOKEN)
     
asyncio.run(main())
```

## roles.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions, has_permissions
from discord.utils import get


class Roles(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, Skadi):
        self.Skadi = Skadi

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Roles commands was set up!")

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
    async def roleall(self, ctx, *, role: discord.Role):
        guild = ctx.guild
        for member in guild.members:
                await member.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f"Added {role.name} to all members in the guild.")

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
    async def delall(self, ctx, *, role: discord.Role):
        guild = ctx.guild
        for member in guild.members:
                await member.remove_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f"Removed {role.name} to all members in the guild.")


    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)  # Correct
    async def addrole(self, ctx, user: discord.Member, *, role: discord.Role):
        if role in user.roles:
            await ctx.send(f"{user.name} already has this role: {role.name}", ephemeral=True)
        else:
            await user.add_roles(role)
            await ctx.send(f"Added {role.name} to {user.name}", ephemeral=True)
            await ctx.message.delete()


    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)  # Correct
    async def delrole(self, ctx, user: discord.Member, *, role: discord.Role):
        if role in user.roles:
            await user.remove_roles(role)
            await ctx.send(f"Removed {role.name} from {user.name}", ephemeral=True)
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"{user.name} Does not have {role.name}", ephemeral=True)




async def setup(Skadi):
    await Skadi.add_cog(Roles(Skadi))
```

Initially, it worked just fine; I even tried undoing and recoding everything, but still no effect.

Comment: Are you able to load the extensions properly?

Comment: Apparently no, I get the prints of the cogs in console, but I'm not sure why they aren't loading, they worked perfectly fine this morning.... @Dominik

Answer (score 0):

You are using the method to load cog files wrong. Instead, your main file should be a `Bot` class and include a `setup_hook` function, where the cog files are loaded.

Here is an [official example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/advanced_startup.py) of how that should look like:

```py
class SkadiBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.default(), case_insensitive=True)

    async def setup_hook(self) -> None:

        # here, we are loading extensions prior to sync to ensure we are syncing interactions defined in those extensions.

        for filename in os.listdir('./misc'):
          if filename.endswith('.py'):
           await self.load_extension(f"misc.{filename[:-3]}")

        for filename in os.listdir('./tickets'):
          if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await self.load_extension(f"tickets.{filename[:-3]}")

        # In overriding setup hook,
        # we can do things that require a bot prior to starting to process events from the websocket.
        # In this case, we are using this to ensure that once we are connected, we sync for the testing guild.
        # You should not do this for every guild or for global sync, those should only be synced when changes happen.
        if self.testing_guild_id:
            guild = discord.Object(self.testing_guild_id)
            # We'll copy in the global commands to test with:
            self.tree.copy_global_to(guild=guild)
            # followed by syncing to the testing guild.
            await self.tree.sync(guild=guild)

        # This would also be a good place to connect to our database and
        # load anything that should be in memory prior to handling events.

Skadi = SkadiBot()


@Skadi.event 
async def on_ready():
    await Skadi.tree.sync()
    print("Da Skadi was awoken")
    SHMOL_GUILD = Skadi.get_guild(SHMOL_ID)
    
    if SHMOL_GUILD:
        SHMOL_MEMBERS = SHMOL_GUILD.member_count
        
        await Skadi.change_presence(
            status=discord.Status.idle,
            activity=discord.Activity(
                type=discord.ActivityType.watching,
                name=f"{SHMOL_MEMBERS} members. | {SHMOL_GUILD.name} "
            )
        )
    else:
        print("SHMOL guild not found.")

    Skadi.add_view(CreateButton())
    Skadi.add_view(CloseButton())

@Skadi.event
async def on_message(message):
    if Skadi.user.mention in message.content.split():
        await message.reply(f'Yes?!', mention_author=False)

async def main():
  async with Skadi:
    await Skadi.start("TOKEN")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    done = asyncio.run(main())
```